# Move ASP.NET Identity store to EF Sql database

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

By default ASP.NET Identity user data is stored in an mdf file.

I want to store the data in a Sql database so that I changed the defaultconnection string in my `web.config` to my EF based connection:

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.StartifyModel.csdl|res://*/Models.StartifyModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.StartifyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MYPC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=mydb;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Now I am getting the error `The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.` as soon as I want to register a user.

I use the default MVC5 project template of VS2013.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try specify the connection string in the format:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1, 1433;Initial Catalog=YourDB;User Id=XXXX;Password=XXXXX;Asynchronous Processing=True;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;Persist Security Info=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And then make sure in Models/IdentityModels.cs you have

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
```

Comment: I have still the same problem with this connection string.

Comment: I created a new project and now it works. I had some issue in the AccountController.

Comment: If you were to change to the non-EF connection string, as per your example, you will get `"Keyword not supported: 'data source'"` instead, as it is not a valid connection string for an EF connection (an EF database was specified in the question). This is not a correct answer for the question asked and will only confuse the issue. *Please revise or remove it.*

Comment: That's the whole point. Switching to a normal data connection here gets this to work. You can still pull your DB tables into your EF data model and get at them through that context.